# PHP corrupted readed file

Tags: php, file, loading

my php file looks like:

```
$file = file("test.cpp");
//checks if file is opened properly...
foreach($file as $line)
{
  echo $lines."<br/>";
}
```

test.cpp file looks like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int a,b,c;
  cin>>a>>b;
  cout<<a;
  return 0;
}
```

but printed output - look at it:

```
#include

int main()
{
int a, b;
float x,y,z;
cin>>a>>b;
cout<return 0;
}
```

it is corrupted, but I have no idea why - original file is in valid state, but only loaded lines are sometimes corrupted

Comment: Check the source of the page.  Maybe your browser is trying to read `<iostream>` as HTML.

Comment: Make sure you're reading the file you believe you're reading; though PHP is well known for adding spurious lines (incredibly always syntactically correct) to C++ source code on a whimsy... PHP is the awakening of skynet

Comment: are you sure your not looking at it via a browser, which will interpret the <> as html

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah, you're right, it tries to read iostream as HTML mark, same as <<a from cout, how can I "tell it" to read it literally?

Comment: Try to wrap the output in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Note that `$line` !== `$lines`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = file("test.cpp");
//checks if file is opened properly...
echo '<pre>';
foreach($file as $line)
{
  echo htmlentities($line);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

ps: no need in `<br>` tag, `<pre>` preserves new line. or just

```
if (file_exists("test.cpp"))
  echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(file_get_contents("test.cpp")) . '</pre>';
```